# In a method, how do I change the values of an existing array and set each of the array variables to a random number between 1 - 100?

Tags: java, methods, random, arraylist

Here is what I have so far:

```
   public class Player {

    private String playerName;
    private double playerScore;

    public Player(String name){
       playerName = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return playerName;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        playerName = name;
    }

    public double getScore(){
        return playerScore;
    }

    public void setScore(double name){
        playerScore = name;
    }
public static void playerArray(ArrayList<Player> arrayPlayerScores){

    for (int i = 0; i < Player.length; i++){

    }


}
```

I am trying to write a Java method that takes an ArrayList of Player objects (from above) and sets each of the Player score instance variables to a random value between 1 and 100

Comment: You've tried literally nothing.  You should start by trying the approach for this if it weren't in a method...

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Player p: arrayPlayerScores){
    p.setScore(Math.random()*100);
}
```

Comment: whoever you are , you do not help this person because you did his homwork for him , and it is not good

Answer (score 0):

You have an ArrayList (not an Array). First, I would add a class level field of type [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

```
private static final Random random = new Random(
    System.currentTimeMillis()); // <-- Like this (maybe).
```

Second, I would use a [for-each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) loop to iterate a `List` named players (not an `ArrayList` called `arrayPlayerScores`).

```
public static void playerArray(List<Player> players) { // <-- like this (maybe).
  for (Player p : players) { // <-- a for-each
    p.setScore(newScore);    // <-- replace newScore with an appropriate call 
                             //     to random (remember, to add 1 to get the range 1
                             //     n).
  }
}
```

Comment: how did you come up with newScore ?